# Strange bug in onedrive. What's the solution?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

Onedrive says that one of my item has bad file name. They can automatically rename it.

What's strange is that there is nothing wrong with the file name. Onedrive cannot change the name automatically.

I changed that manually and then Onedrive still complain.

Also I think this bug must have made the whole computer slow.

[image]

As you see. The file name is UtilitiesQuick.h. There is no illegal character whatsoever. I also changed the file name to FormerUtilitiesQuick.h

And One drive still complain.

NOthing I can do fix it. Clicking Rename doesn't work. Changing the file name manually doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe the illegal characters are not visible to you or me. Let it replace them, then rename the file.

Comment: It’s probably the **file extension** that’s the problem

Comment: @Ramhound If .h was a problem, a lot of C and C++ developers would be upset.

Comment: It’s either the name of the file or the file extension of the file. I don’t begin to explain the reason OneDrive has a problem but I know that, at work, my OneDrive client doesn’t sync file extensions that my personal OneDrive account does.  The author should try changing the file extension and if that still doesn’t work [edit] the question.  I can also guarantee the pc is connected to a corporate network

Comment: I wonder if there is an alternate data stream for that file, and it is complaining about that but not showing it. [Hidden in plain sight: Alternate Data Streams](https://davidhamann.de/2019/02/23/hidden-in-plain-sight-alternate-data-streams/) shows a way to list the alternate data streams if there are any.

Comment: @Ramhound, "_at work, my OneDrive client doesn’t sync file extensions that my personal OneDrive account does_" to some extent that's a choice made by your systems administrators. As admin for our M365 environment I can choose which file extensions are included and which are to be skipped

Comment: @roaima - Yes; I know; That’s why I made my suggestion to change the file extension.

Comment: user4951, please double-check you don't have leading or trailing space in the filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a bug, as I moved the file out of OenDrive and opened the file, with its content being garbage. The problem is *not* with the file name, but it's content, as there are plenty of other `.h` and `.m` files in the directory without the problem.

- Onedrive just sends the wrong message, as I deleted the file and it works, indicating the issue is definitely not the `.h` file; a possibility is that OneDrive expects a text file for `.h` files, then finds out it doesn't contain content for an `.h` file.

Comment: Why would OneDrive care about a file's contents and where have you found documentation that states only certain file types/file contents are allowed to be uploaded, as that simply doesn't jive. OneDrive doesn't open files to see the content before uploading, it simply uploads them to a server's storage drive _(it's no different than copying the file to another partition, the only difference is the file's being transported over a network versus SATA)_.

Comment: I have no idea. In any case, the data in that file is corrupt. I deleted that one file and it works. It's definitely the content and not the file name. Nothing is wrong with the filename.